# jdbc is not able to find data flushed by jpa repository in the same transaction

Tags: spring, oracle, jpa, jdbc, transactions

I have a JUnit 5 testcase which is annotated with @Transactional and it is calling save service (which uses JPA saveandFlush) first, and trying to retrieve the same data/entity by using find service, which is using plain JDBC for searching, but it is not able to find that entity.

When I tried using isolation of the transaction as read_uncommitted it threw exception saying "java.sql.SQLException: READ_COMMITTED and SERIALIZABLE are the only valid transaction levels" please note that I am using Oracle database.

Is there any other way we can read the data which is present in same transaction by JDBC code?

Comment: If you don't see the data, then you are not using the same transaction, and the transaction that saved the data is not committed.

Comment: Please add the code you are using.

Comment: If you use *two different* database **connections** (one for JPA and one for JDBC) you will never see the uncommited changes of the other connection. If you use only *one connection* you of course see *all changes* independent of the commit.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber agree, had to use spring given jdbc template, so that jpa and jdbc both use the same transaction. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle does not implement *Read Uncommited* [isolation level](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/cncpt/data-concurrency-and-consistency.html#GUID-2A0FDFF0-5F72-4476-BFD2-060A20EA1685), so you will not be able to see uncommited changes from other sessions.

Answer (score 1):

As Mark Rotteveel and Marmite Bomber said, two different transactions/connections(JPA and JDBC) can not see each other's uncommitted data, specially for application having Oracle database.

I had to use spring managed jdbc template so that JPA and the JDBC template uses the same transaction and data is visible to each other.